# Thinkpad T480 Ubuntu 18.04 - Wifi Slow

Tags: networking, wireless, intel, iwlwifi

Hope everyone is well and healthy.

Recently, I've noticed that my wireless connection connection on my Thinkpad has slowed down. I'm not really sure why this has happened. Haven't had any major changes to my machine in the past several weeks. Only several weeks ago the download speed on my laptop was around 90-100 mbps. Now it's hovering around 15-20. The connection on my phone is strong.

I currently use a Nighthawk Wifi Extender. When I connect to the non-extended wifi and move closer to the router, I get speeds around 40-50 mbps. Usually it would be 100mbps+.

I've tried solutions 2 and 3 from this link: https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

For solution 2, I wasn't able to run `sudo rmmod iwlwifi` as I got this error message:
`rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is in use by: iwlmvm`

One thing I noticed was that the power management was on when running `sudo tlp-stat` and `sudo iwconfig`. I turned off power management via the TLP GUI. But after running those two same commands, the output is still telling me that the power management is on. However, I did see an increase in my download speed to about ~30-40mbps.

I've included some information about my hardware below. Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide that would be helpful. Thank you in advance for any input!

Running `sudo iwconfig`:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NIGHTHAWK5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: B0:39:56:90:B0:AA   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:119   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
```

Running `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 78
       serial: 48:89:e7:9b:56:27
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-46-generic firmware=36.9f0a2d68.0 ip=192.168.50.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 memory:f2000000-f2001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 98:fa:9b:0a:30:90
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:127 memory:f2100000-f211ffff
```

Running `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:56a6 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```